# Weird behaviour with jQuery datepicker in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have added a jQuery datepicker to my MVC application and it seems to be working perfectly in all browsers except for Internet Explorer.

On click of the cell the calendar control appears but clicking through the months using the navigation icons seems to stop after varying amount of clicks. The date cells then become unclickable and I am unable to set the date.

Has anyone ever seen this issue before? And if so was there a solution available?

My javascript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#expirydate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
});
```

And my HTML is as follows:

```
<label for="expirydate">Expiry Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="expirydate" class="datepicker" name="expirydate" /><br />
```

Comment: Could you provide us an example to show your problem?

Comment: I am using jQuery datepicker on one of my sites and I've just tested it as working on there. We'd need to see your specific example.
This sounds like the behaviour you get when you specify a limit for the date range.

Comment: I have ammended the question to show the code that I am currently using, I should stress this works well on chrome, firefox, safari and opera my problem occurs only in IE10

Comment: any errors on the console?

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference in relation to jquery.validate.min.js, line 48 character 199

Comment: Can you post your validation code? Or even better: create a reduced test case. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ugHkp